# Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd - VS 2010 win7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, memory, matrix

I'm doing C++ after a long time and there are some things troubling my mind. I found similar questions here but none of them solves my problem. So, what's the deal?

I have

```
SomeClass*** world;
```

which presents matrix of pointers to SomeClass objects.

Latter, in constructor, when I try to initialize it, a do it like this

```
for(int i = 0; i<20;i++)
    for(int j = 0;j<20;j++)
        world[i][j] = new SomeClass();
```

And it breaks with message: Access violation reading location 0xcdcdcdcd.
I read what this message could mean, but still, I have no idea how to make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `world` needs to be allocated first.You dereference a pointer that points to something random.

Comment: You need to learn C++ again from scratch. Your code demonstrates some fundamental misunderstandings as to the operation of the language. Nobody should be even trying to write code like this.

Comment: Please don't try to be a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) if you're not experienced enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's super important to understand what you *get* when you declare a variable. As in, what actually gets created in memory.

So let's take a look at `SomeClass*** world;`. What does this *get* you? Does it get you a matrix of pointers to `SomeClass`? No, it doesn't. In fact, you might be surprised to know that this gets you one thing and one thing only - a single pointer. Yes, that's right, just one pointer. You've defined this `world` variable which is a pointer and that's all you get from it. That single pointer.

This pointer should then be used to point at other pointers that in turn point at pointers to `SomeClass`. However, those things it points at don't exist yet. So when you iterate `i` and `j` up to 20 and do `world[i][j]`, you're attempting to access a matrix of pointers that simply doesn't exist yet.

Now to make what you've written work, while still using `SomeClass***`, you would need to allocate the matrix of pointers:

```
world = new SomeClass**[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  world[i] = new SomeClass*[20];
}
```

So first we allocate an array of 20 `SomeClass**`, then we make each of those pointers point at an allocated array of 20 `SomeClass*`. This gives you what you want...

but **hold on** - this is ugly. This is not how C++ should be written. So much dynamic allocation for no reason at all. It also means that you have to remember to `delete` everything when you're done with it - and that is also ugly. This can all be made much easier if you don't rely on dynamic allocation. You could just create a multidimensional array instead of using pointers and already your life would be much easier:

```
SomeClass* world[20][20];
```

So now `world` is a 20 by 20 array of pointers to `SomeClass`. You actually *get* that in memory. You don't just get a pointer like you did before. You get an entire multidimensional array of pointers! Lucky you.

Now, you could make it even better by simply not using pointers at all. At the moment, you would need to dynamically allocate your `SomeClass` objects and stick pointers to them in the array. But why not have an array of `SomeClass` instead?

```
SomeClass world[20][20];
```

Now you have a multidimensional array of `SomeClass` objects! Life doesn't get much better than this. You don't have to manually allocate or delete anything. You're given a whole multidimensional array in memory where each element is already a `SomeClass` object, ready for your service.

We can even improve the safety further by using containers from the standard library. If you're using C++03, you could use a `std::vector<std::vector<SomeObject> >` but this might be a little overkill. However, C++11 introduces a type that neatly replaces using traditional arrays and makes it a whole lot safer: `std::array`. You could use it like this:

```
std::array<std::array<SomeObject, 20>, 20> world;
```

Comment: Thanks for this really deep clarification :)
I will use SomeClass* world[20][20] (matrix of pointers) because latter I need to fill matrix with pointers of two different subclasses

Answer (score 3):

The actual error you get is from using a pointer that hasn't been initialized. 0xcdcdcdcd is the "fill pattern" for memory in Visual Studio. It is choosen so that you "notice" when you use it - it will cause memory access violation.

How to solve it: Google for "how to allocate two dimenisonal array in c++".

Answer (score 3):

Just allocate an array of 20x20 as a member (or on the stack) and then fill it:

```
SomeClass *world[20][20];
for ...
```

If the size is not constant, you need to allocate row by row.